# FOSUserBundle wont show up register or login form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm creating Symfony 3 project with FOSUserBundle which I installed using command:

```
$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"
```

This is my security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

#        in_memory:
#            memory: ~


    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
#        dev:
#            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
#            security: false

        main:

            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

            #anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/group/(\d)+/((delete)|(edit)), role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/group/(my)|(new), role: ROLE_USER }
```

**Problem is:** on localhost in dev environment it works fine but when I move it on a shared hosting, it just **won't show me login or register page**, it just redirects (301) me on main page again, when I try to access /login page. Nothing in the ubuntu or symfony logs.

I'm so frustrated, please, anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: did you cleared the cache? (or if you are on shared host, then manually delete the `var/cache/prod` directory).

Comment: Yes, I just did, that didn't help, unfortunately